# Erro de sintaxe no SQL ao iniciar o OW2 Orchestra

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, ant

Recentemente, baixei o software OW2 orchestra. No manual de usuário, após percorrer todos os passos de configuração (Estou usando MySQL como meu BD. As outras configurações são as padrões, incluindo o uso do hibernate) , cheguei ás instruções que orientam como iniciá-lo:

> Orchestra is a webapp that can be deployed on Tomcat. So starting
>   Orchestra in fact starts Tomcat with the correct environment. This can
>   be performed from the installation directory with the following
>   command line :
>
> cd orchestra-cxf-tomcat-4.9.0 >ant start

Quando uso este comando, no entanto, acontecem alguns erros relacionados á sintaxe do SQL (?).

Eis alguns enxertos relevantes do log:

```
 [echo] Starting orchestra
 [java] 19:57:34,152 WARN  [SoapUI] Missing folder [C:\Users\Victor\Documents\Orchestra\.\ext] for external libraries
 [java] 19:57:34,501 WARN  [DefaultSoapUICore] Failed to load settings from [C:\Users\Victor\Documents\Orchestra\tomcat\temp\gwt-soapui\soapui-settings.xml:1:1: error: Unexpected end of file after null], creating new
 [java] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.granite.config.GraniteConfigListener).
 [java] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
 [java] [INFO] Started bridged http service
 [java] nov 13, 2016 7:57:48 PM org.ow2.orchestra.StartupListener contextInitialized
 [java] INFORMAÇÕES: OSGi framework started
 [java] nov 13, 2016 7:57:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
 [java] GRAVE: Unsuccessful: create table DEF_ACTIVITY (DBID_ bigint not null, CLASS_ varchar(255) not null, NAME_ varchar(255), UUID_ varchar(500), CHILD_NODE_ bigint, FAULT_QNAME_ varchar(255), catchVariableDefinition bigint, IS_DEFAULT_CH_ bit, DEL_JOIN_FAIL_ bit, EXEC_SRC_ASYNC bit, SCOPE_ bigint, TARG_JOIN_COND_ bigint, EXT_ACTIVITY_NAME varchar(255), EXT_ACTIVITY_ID bigint, PARTNER_LINK_ varchar(255), OPERATION_NAME_ varchar(255), IN_VAR_NAME_ varchar(255), OUT_VAR_NAME_ varchar(255), ONE_WAY_ bit, PT_QNAME_ varchar(255), ANON_OUT_MESS_ bigint, ANON_IN_MESS_ bigint, MSG_TYPE_QNAME_ varchar(255), MSG_EXCHANGE_ varchar(255), CREATE_INST_ bit, OP_KEY_ varchar(3999), INPUT_TYPE_ varchar(255), VALIDATE_ bit, ISOLATED_ bit, EXIT_ON_FAULT_ bit, NODE_ bigint, COND_ bigint, ACTIVITY_ bigint, ELSE_ACTIVITY_ bigint, COUNTER_NAME_ varchar(255), PARALLEL_ bit, SUC_BRANCHES_ bit, START_COUNT_ bigint, FINAL_COUNT_ bigint, COMPL_COND_ bigint, DURATION_ bigint, DEADLINE_ bigint, FAULT_VAR_ varchar(255), TARGET_ varchar(255), INBOUND_PROCESS_ bigint, EXT_PROCESS_ bigint, primary key (DBID_)) ENGINE=InnoDB
 [java] nov 13, 2016 7:57:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
 [java] GRAVE: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE DEF_ACTIVITY (DBID_ BIGINT NOT NULL, CLASS_ VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, NAME_ VARCHAR(255), UUID_ VARCHAR(500), CHILD_NODE_ BIGINT, FAULT_QNAME_ VARCHAR(255), CATCHVARIABLEDEFINITION BIGINT, IS_DEFAULT_CH_ BIT, DEL_JOIN_FAIL_ BIT, EXEC_SRC_ASYNC BIT, SCOPE_ BIGINT, TARG_JOIN_COND_ BIGINT, EXT_ACTIVITY_NAME VARCHAR(255), EXT_ACTIVITY_ID BIGINT, PARTNER_LINK_ VARCHAR(255), OPERATION_NAME_ VARCHAR(255), IN_VAR_NAME_ VARCHAR(255), OUT_VAR_NAME_ VARCHAR(255), ONE_WAY_ BIT, PT_QNAME_ VARCHAR(255), ANON_OUT_MESS_ BIGINT, ANON_IN_MESS_ BIGINT, MSG_TYPE_QNAME_ VARCHAR(255), MSG_EXCHANGE_ VARCHAR(255), CREATE_INST_ BIT, OP_KEY_ VARCHAR(3999), INPUT_TYPE_ VARCHAR(255), VALIDATE_ BIT, ISOLATED_ BIT, EXIT_ON_FAULT_ BIT, NODE_ BIGINT, COND_ BIGINT, ACTIVITY_ BIGINT, ELSE_ACTIVITY_ BIGINT, COUNTER_NAME_ VARCHAR(255), PARALLEL_ BIT, SUC_BRANCHES_ BIT, START_COUNT_ BIGINT, FINAL_COUNT_ BIGINT, COMPL_COND_ BIGINT, DURATION_ BIGINT, DEADLINE_ BIGINT, FAULT_VAR_ VARCHAR(255), TARGET_ VARCHAR(255), INBOUND_PROCESS_ BIGINT, EXT_PROCESS_ BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (DBID_)) ENGINE=[*]INNODB "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
 [java] create table DEF_ACTIVITY (DBID_ bigint not null, CLASS_ varchar(255) not null, NAME_ varchar(255), UUID_ varchar(500), CHILD_NODE_ bigint, FAULT_QNAME_ varchar(255), catchVariableDefinition bigint, IS_DEFAULT_CH_ bit, DEL_JOIN_FAIL_ bit, EXEC_SRC_ASYNC bit, SCOPE_ bigint, TARG_JOIN_COND_ bigint, EXT_ACTIVITY_NAME varchar(255), EXT_ACTIVITY_ID bigint, PARTNER_LINK_ varchar(255), OPERATION_NAME_ varchar(255), IN_VAR_NAME_ varchar(255), OUT_VAR_NAME_ varchar(255), ONE_WAY_ bit, PT_QNAME_ varchar(255), ANON_OUT_MESS_ bigint, ANON_IN_MESS_ bigint, MSG_TYPE_QNAME_ varchar(255), MSG_EXCHANGE_ varchar(255), CREATE_INST_ bit, OP_KEY_ varchar(3999), INPUT_TYPE_ varchar(255), VALIDATE_ bit, ISOLATED_ bit, EXIT_ON_FAULT_ bit, NODE_ bigint, COND_ bigint, ACTIVITY_ bigint, ELSE_ACTIVITY_ bigint, COUNTER_NAME_ varchar(255), PARALLEL_ bit, SUC_BRANCHES_ bit, START_COUNT_ bigint, FINAL_COUNT_ bigint, COMPL_COND_ bigint, DURATION_ bigint, DEADLINE_ bigint, FAULT_VAR_ varchar(255), TARGET_ varchar(255), INBOUND_PROCESS_ bigint, EXT_PROCESS_ bigint, primary key (DBID_)) ENGINE=InnoDB [42001-144]
 [java] nov 13, 2016 7:57:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
 [java] GRAVE: Unsuccessful: create table DEF_COPY_ELT (DBID_ bigint not null, KEEP_SRC_ELT_ bit, IGNORE_MISS_DATA_ bit, FROM_ bigint, TO_ bigint, INVOKE_IN_ID_ bigint, INDEX_ integer, INVOKE_OUT_ID_ bigint, REPLY_ID_ bigint, RECEIVE_IN_ID_ bigint, ASSIGN_ID_ bigint, ASSIGN_INDEX_ integer, ON_MSG_IN_ID_ bigint, ON_EVT_IN_ID_ bigint, primary key (DBID_)) ENGINE=InnoDB
 [java] nov 13, 2016 7:57:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
```

Atentem-se ás linhas começando com **GRAVE**.

As configurações do MySQL no **hibernate.properties** são as seguintes:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc\:h2\:file\:/tmp/orchestra-db/orchestra_core.db (antigo)
#hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql
hibernate.connection.username=root@localhost
hibernate.connection.password=8ct8b&r
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

**"Resolvido"!** Caso interesse a alguém: Eu desisti do MySQL e passei a usar o H2. No fim, o arquivo *hibernate.properties* ficou assim (não inclui as linhas comentadas (as que começam com *#*)):

```
hibernate.dialect                      org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class      org.h2.Driver
hibernate.connection.url               jdbc:h2:file:db_orchestra
hibernate.connection.username          sa
hibernate.connection.password

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false
hibernate.use_sql_comments=false

hibernate.connection.isolation=2

hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection=50
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
```